# Delphi "While" Performance decreases when mouse not moving over FireMonkey Application

Tags: delphi, opengl, firemonkey, onkeydown

I am playing around a little with Delphi + openGL. Because I am lazy, I wanted to use FireMonkey to make a form for me.
So I made a FireMonkeyHD application, initialized GL, rendered a basic cube... and found some strange behavior. When I do not move my mouse, I get about 10FPS. When I move my mouse, performance rises easily to 500FPS and (obviously) more. What could that be?
 *Note: I start rendering with an onKeyDown Event in the Main Thread...

For a better understanding, two pics:
[image: Application w/o mouse move]
[image: Application w wild mouse move]

Some code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
{ ... }
;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
      Shift: TShiftState);
  private
    degen
    : IDeGEn;
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  DeGEnFactory
  : TDeGEnFactory;
begin
  { ... }
  // Load DeGEn
  degen := DeGEnFactory.newDeGEn(WindowHandleToPlatform(Form1.Handle).Wnd);

  // Initialize
  degen.get3D.init(600, 800);
  degen.get3D.setOnRender(function : Boolean
  var
    v3d
    : R3DVector;
  begin
    Result := true;
    self.Caption := IntToStr(degen.get3D.getFPS);
    v3d.z := 0.01;
    degen.get3D.getCamera.move(v3d);
    degen.get3D.renderTest;
  end);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Shut down DeGEn
  { ... }
end;

procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  // Start rendering
  degen.startRendering;
end;

end.
```

And `startRendering` looks like this:

```
procedure TDeGEn.startRendering;
var
  msg
  : TMsg;
begin
  if isRendering then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;

  isRendering := true;
  while GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) do
  begin
    TranslateMessage(msg);
    DispatchMessage(msg);

    if not degen3D.render then
    begin
      Break;
    end;
  end;

  isRendering := false;
end;
```

As you might easily notice, the camera just moves away from the cube with a speed dependent on the FPS. Also I get the FPS displayed as form caption.

Comment: This was common behavior in really old Windows applications. They will not redraw the screen unless the screen is marked "dirty." Moving the mouse over part of the screen is a sure fire way to mark a control dirty and force a re-paint. This is probably not the culprit in your situation, but I suspect that it is somehow tied to your message pump, and moving the cursor around increases the frequency that something in your message pump necessary for drawing occurs.

Comment: Speak of the devil, I believe this is your culprit: `while GetMessage(msg, 0, 0, 0) do`. If you have no pending window messages the loop is skipped altogether. It's been a while, does Pascal have Do While? :) You want to invoke this loop at least once to get `degen3D.render` to do something, whether there is a waiting message or not.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman: sounds interesting. Problem is: my program does not care about the form being redrawn. It just has a counter in the loop (in the render function to be precise). So even if the whole thing is not redrawn, it should not affect my loop, or am I wrong?

Comment: Well, the only part of your code that does rendering that I can see is  in your message pump. Your loop for the message pump will bail-out early if no messages are pending.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman: do while? Would that not have the same effect? I mean, should it then not just wait after the loop closure instead of before? But I will try this. I will make it a while(true) loop.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman: tried the while(true) w/o GetMessage and tried PeekMessage. No change :(

Comment: @Andon You got that all wrong. When the queue is empty, GetMessage blocks.

Comment: @Marco Why did you add a message loop at all? Your app already has one. Why do you need a second one?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That's what I thought I said? Or at least that is what I meant to say. Pascal does not agree with me; the point I was trying to make is that the loop body does not execute until there is at least one message in the queue.

Comment: @Andon That's not what you said. You said the loop body will never be entered.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It's not about why I use a message loop. It's about why the loop slows down. You are absolutely right. This is a product of complete lazyness. But the behaviour should still be the same as if this was the main message loop, or am I wrong with this assumption?

Comment: If you had provided an SSCCE, we could run the program and investigate. I would do so. But with no SSCCE, I cannot.

Answer (score 5):

The `GetMessage` **waits** for a message.
If you don't move the mouse very little messages get into the message-queue and rendering will be slow, because the CPU is stuck waiting for GetMessage to return.

When you move the mouse lots of messages get created; the message-queue is full and GetMessage returns almost instantly.

Note that doing a messageloop like this has not been necessary since Windows 3.1.

Also note that Microsoft warns against implementing the messageloop like this.
From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Because the return value can be nonzero, zero, or -1, avoid code like
>   this:
>
> `while (GetMessage( lpMsg, hWnd, 0, 0)) ...`
>
> The possibility of a -1 return value in the case that hWnd is an
>   invalid parameter (such as referring to a window that has already been
>   destroyed) means that such code can lead to fatal application errors.
>   Instead, use code like this:

```
BOOL bRet;`

while( (bRet = GetMessage( &msg, hWnd, 0, 0 )) != 0) {
    if (bRet == -1)` `    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    } else {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    } 
}
```

Anyway there is no need to do the loop like that.
Instead put a timer on the form, and put the code inside the `OnTimer` event.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //DoRendering
end;
```

If the normal timer is too slow, there are a great many high resolution timers out there. JVCL has done and unDelphiX has one too.
See here: http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-high-performance-timer-tstopwatch.htm
or here: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvTimer

**Handling Windows messages in a CPU intensive loop**
We do not muck about with the messageloop anymore (not since Delphi 1.0).
Use `Application.ProcessMessages` instead if you find that the application is unresponsive due to your loop hogging all CPU time.

**WM_TIMER messages are low priority**
If you use the default timer, you will run into unreliability issues.
This is because Windows regards `WM_TIMER` messages (the messages that TTimer looks for) as low priority.
If Windows is busy with other tasks it will compress multiple waiting `WM_TIMER` messages into one to avoid creating a backlog of timer messages.
It does the same thing with `WM_PAINT` messages.
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

One trick to avoid this is to structure the loop using a high resolution timer (this does not depend on the message loop), or to use a simple endless loop with `Application.ProcessMessages` and a `sleep()` delay.

Comment: tried while(true) w/o GetMessage and tried PeekMessage. No change :(

Comment: Well, your edit does solve the problem, thanks a lot. But unfortunately it does not answer the question "What could that be" since, as I mentioned, even w/o GetMessage the speed drops.

Comment: Drop the whole messagething, TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage slow things down as well. Just use a timer.

Comment: yes, that's what I am doing now, but still, I want to know why this is happening so that I can avoid this problem in the future. The loop should not slow down if I do not use GetMessage/PeekMessage!

Comment: `TranslateMessage` and `DispatchMessage` are slowing it down.

Comment: I also removed those... and even if they are, this still would not explain that strange behavior.

Comment: yeah, but I am talking about nothing more than a mere while ... do loop. Unless the while loop is dependent on a WM_TIMER message, I do not see a connection...

Comment: *Also note that Microsoft warns against implementing the
message loop like this.* In fact the call to GetMessage in the code is fine. It can never return an error because @Msg is valid, and because the window handle parameter passed is 0. Raymond Chen has blogged on this subject.